# How do I evaluate the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}n((1+1/n)^n-e)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Could anyone show me how to evaluate this limit?

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n-e\right)
$$

Thanks!

Comment: A limit is evaluated not solved.

Comment: @AméricoTavares Thank you for explanation!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: See my answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/194880/5418, where you will find more accurate result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see another way 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n-e\right)=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}en\left(\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}{e}-1\right)=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}en\ln\left(\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}{e}\right)\times \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(\displaystyle\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}{e}-1\right)}{\ln\left(\displaystyle\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}{e}\right)}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}en\ln\left(\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}{e}\right)=  $$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}e \left(n^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-n\right)=-\frac{e}{2} $$
where I used $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to1} \frac{x-1}{\ln x}=1$, and then
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(x^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-x\right)= $$
$$\lim_{y\to0} \left(\frac{1}{y^2}\ln\left(1+y\right)-\frac{1}{y}\right)= $$
$$\lim_{y\to0} \left(\frac{\ln(1+y)-y}{y^2}\right)= $$
that by l'Hôpital's rule turns into
$$ \lim_{y\to0} -\frac{1}{2(y+1)}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Chris.

Comment: @David: welcome! :-)

Answer (score 6):

Since $\log(1+x)=x-x^2/2+O(x^3)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)
&=n\left(\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)\\
&=1-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, since $e^x=1+x+O\left(x^2\right)$, we have
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e\left(1-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)
$$
From here, it is easy to see that
$$
n\left(\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n-e\right)=-\frac{e}{2}+O\left(\frac1n\right)
$$
Thus,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n-e\right)=-\frac{e}{2}
$$

Comment: In the first equation, it seems to me that the right-hand side of the expression is divided by *n*, whilst the left-hand side isn't. Is that right or do I miss something?

Comment: Sorry, I see now.

Comment: I assume you are using Taylor's polynomial to solve this. I am in my first year at college and don't really know what these are about, should have told you before. (It took me a while to realize what it was.) Nonetheless, thank you very much for your help! If you see any other solution, please do let me know.

Comment: Yes. The approximations that I use above are Taylor series. This limit might be workable by L'Hospital, but I haven't looked into it.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to do with L'Hopital too but the derivation is a bit lengthy:

$$A = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\left(1+1/n\right)^n - e}{1/n}$$

Having $0/0$ we can try to use L'Hopital.

Because

$$ \frac{d}{dn} \left(1+1/n\right)^n
= \frac{d}{dn} \exp\left(n \ln\left(1+1/n\right)\right)
= \left(1+1/n\right)^n \left(\ln\left(1+1/n\right) + \frac{n\left(-1/n^2\right)}{1+1/n}\right)
$$

we have

$$A = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\left(1+1/n\right)^n \left(\ln\left(1+1/n\right) - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)}{-1/n^2}
= e \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\left(\ln\left(1+1/n\right) - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)}{-1/n^2}$$

Which is $0/0$ again (Because $\ln(1+\epsilon)\approx \epsilon$ for $\epsilon\ll 1$) , using L'Hopital once more,

$$A = e \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{-1/n^2}{1+1/n} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)}{2/n^3}
= e \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{-n^2}{2(n+1)^2}
= -\frac{e}{2}
$$