# Calculate this limit without L'Hopital's rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have to calculate this limit whitout using L'Hopital's rule or Taylor polynomials:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = (1+\frac{x}{2})^{\frac{1}{x}}
$$
I know how to make it using L'Hopital and that the result is $ e^{\frac{1}{2}} $ ,but I'm getting nowhere when I try without it. Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What is your definition of $e^x$?

Comment: The proposed duplicate is in fact not a duplicate.

Comment: @DavidMitra A stronger statement about this type of convergence: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/292422/290189.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard $1^{\infty}$ indeterminate form.
A useful result for such limits is:
$$ \lim_{x \to a} ~(1+f(x))^{g(x)} = e^{\lim_{x \to a}f(x) \cdot g(x)} ~ \text{if} ~ \lim_{x \to a}f(x) = 0 ~\text{and} \lim_{x \to a}g(x)=\infty $$
In your question, $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{2}$ and $g(x)=\dfrac1x$
$$ \therefore \lim_{x \to a} \left(1+\dfrac{x}{2}\right)^{\frac1x} = e^{\lim_{x \to a} \frac{x}{2}\cdot\frac1x} = e^{\frac12}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $$L=\lim_{x \to a} f(x)^{g(x)}\to 1^{\infty}$$
then
$$L=\exp[\lim_{x\to a} [g(x)(f(x)-1))]$$
So here
$$L=\exp[\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}(1+\frac{x}{2}-1)]=e^{1/2}.$$